# Integration testing for a background job in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber

I'm building an application that has two parts.
The first one is periodically fetching a data from an external resource and populates a database.
The second one is displaying it at a user request.

It is very easy to cover the second part with integration tests. The question is, how do I write integration tests, namely Cucumber tests, for the first part? Do I need to write integration tests for this? Or unit tests are enough?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw a similar sample in the book.

[The cucumber book](http://pragprog.com/book/hwcuc/the-cucumber-book)

You may take a peak into the source code provided

Chapter 9. Dealing with Message Queues and Asynchronous
Components